# Generating Excel/CSV template on Atlassian Jira

Tags: project-management, jira

In Azure DevOps, we can nicely integrate the project with Excel.

But I'm finding it very difficult in Jira Project management to upload tasks and issues through Excel. Is there a way to export the template to excel and then use same template to import Epic, issues and tasks?

It doesn't makes sense to build a CSV format on our own for every project which might have different configuration. Not looking for paid options as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally found it.

---

- We can export the CSV template from:
  Filter > Advanced Issue Search > Export CSV

---

- CSV can also be imported from:
  Filter > Advanced Issue Search > OverFlow Menu > Import CSV

---

- To update Issues you can't use the above method as "Issue Key" field is not available in the above method. "Issue Key" is available from this method if you have Administrator Access:
  Settings > System > External System Import > CSV

---